Tail Probability of r.v. $X_t$ from a Langevin diffusion
Backgrounds: An overdamped Langevin dynamics on $\mathbb{R}$ is defined as the solution to the following SDE:
$$
dX_t=-\nabla V(X_t)\,dt+\sqrt{2\beta^{-1}}\,dB_t,\qquad X_0=x_0.
$$
If $V(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$, $X$ becomes an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. Transforming via $f(t,x)=xe^t$ and using Itô's formula, we get
$$
X_t=x_0e^{-t}+\sqrt{2\beta^{-1}}\int^t_0e^{-(t-s)}\,dB_s.
$$
Hence, $X$ is a Gaussian process with $\renewcommand{\P}{\operatorname{P}}\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{E}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}\newcommand{\Abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}\newcommand{\ABs}[1]{\biggl|#1\biggr|}\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\|#1\|}\newcommand{\Norm}[1]{\left\|#1\right\|}\newcommand{\NOrm}[1]{\biggl\|#1\biggr\|}\newcommand{\Brace}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}\newcommand{\BRace}[1]{\biggl\{#1\biggr\}}\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\left(#1\right)}\newcommand{\Paren}[1]{\biggr(#1\biggl)}\newcommand{\brac}[1]{\langle#1\rangle}\newcommand{\Brac}[1]{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}\newcommand{\BRac}[1]{\biggl\langle#1\biggr\rangle}\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle#1\right|}\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right\rangle}\newcommand{\Square}[1]{\left[#1\right]}\newcommand{\SQuare}[1]{\biggl[#1\biggr]}X_t\sim\mathrm{N}_1\paren{x_0e^{-t},\beta^{-1}(1-e^{-2t})}$.
Question: What can we say about the tail probability of $X_t$, under the general assumption that $V$ is $V(x)=x^p/p$?
Specifically, I am trying to establish the integrability of
$$
P_tG(x_0)=\E_{x_0}[G(X_t)]
$$
where $G(x)=e^{\kappa V(x)}\;(\kappa\in\R)$, under the assumption that $V$ behaves like a polynomial in the sense that
$$V(x)=O(x^p)\qquad(\abs{x}\to\infty).$$
Updates: Here is what I've found. In the regime $p<1$, $V'$ becomes bounded on $\R$, therefore a classical result from Malliavin calculus or heat equation can be applied, see, for example, Kohatsu-Higa (2003). Thus, we can conclude that the density $p_t$ of $X_t$ has a Gaussial tail: for all $T>0$ there exists $A_T,a_T>0$ and $y\in\R$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{A_T\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{a_T\abs{y-x}^2}{2t}}\le p_t(x,y)\le\frac{A_T}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{\abs{y-x}^2}{2a_Tt}},\qquad t\in(0,T]
$$
What a tight bound!
